# How to create stand alone UI Automator test using UI Automator testing framework

Tags: android, android-studio, android-uiautomator

I use Appium to create instrumented tests. I would like to switch over to a native testing client for Android, and there appear to be a couple [options](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing)

```
1) Espresso testing framework (for single app)
2) UI Automator testing framework (for multiple apps)
```

and as per the suggestion, I imagine I should use `UI Automator testing framework` since I will be testing multiple instances of the same app on multiple devices.

However, all tutorials and information on how to use `UI Automator testing framework` indicate its usage from within an Android application project.

So my question is, can I create a stand alone project, say like a Gradle IntelliJ project that is not coded from within an Android Studio project?

Is this technically possible?

**edit**

Even the [sample app](https://github.com/android/testing-samples/tree/master/ui/uiautomator) includes the test within an android app module project. If I can define any apk build I want, I guess I have no problem using an application project. Maybe that's the direction I need to go in?

**edit**

Just looking at the sample test, it looks like the framework is deeply coupled within the android project, and I'm disappointed I can't make a stand alone framework.

Comment: I found a sample project, so I'll check this out for now https://github.com/android/testing-samples/tree/master/ui/uiautomator/BasicSample

Comment: Still in a very early stage but https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public might be what you are looking for to run uiautomator tests on multiple devices

Answer (score 1):

What I learned is I can create a separate app module with no app source, and only test code, then use a script to automate the install of the build from another app module.

However, the test code is run internally to the device as an APK, and thus testing is restricted to one device only AFAIK for now.